# How do I use Plutus to check that payment has been made to a native script?

Tags: plutus, validator, native, multisig

If I want to check that payment has been made to a Plutus script, then I can use the function `valueLockedBy txinfo vhash` where vhash is the ValidatorHash of the Plutus script. Is there an analogous function to check that payment has been paid to a native script?

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by "native script" vs "Plutus script."

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxPUpxj2D7c) introduces native scripts. (As you can see, they are distinct from scripts written in Plutus.)